# Search a source code using curl along with substr_count, use a specific count, and get all the line

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to view a html source code of a website. I am new to curl, but so far I accomplished the first step. However my purpose, is to use substr_count and use its result in retrieving the line holding this word. For example :
mailto exist 3 times in the source code. I need to use the third one and get the text for it like that: mailto:question@question.com. The other "mailto" text my contain other emails.

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'website.com';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$content=curl_exec($ch);
$html = substr_count(htmlspecialchars($content),"mailto");
echo $html;
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: Is it always the third one you want or is it the last one. Be more specific please

Comment: No the third one

Comment: Use `strpos` to find the first occurrence, use the resulting position in calculating the offset to call strpos again to find the next one, and so on … Or, familiarize yourself with regular expressions instead - because you want the part after the mailto: as well, and that is easier to achieve using a properly formatted regex pattern, otherwise you would have to advance through the string from the found position and figure out where the value you are looking for actually ends.

Comment: <?php

$text = file_get_contents('text.txt');    
$values = preg_split('/[\n,]+/', $text);
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");

foreach($values as $url) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$content=curl_exec($ch);
$html = strstr(htmlspecialchars($content),"data: { mailto:");
$email = substr($html,22,30);
curl_close($ch);
}

fwrite($myfile, $email);
fwrite($myfile, "\r\n");
fclose($myfile);


?>

Comment: I did it, but it is not looping with foreach to get each email ! Why ?